# Call function(d){} in .attr()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I tried to set numbers as translate attributes of groups.

But, to set the numbers, I need to access data.

I found it's impossible to access data with `function(d){}`.

How to access data in `.attr()`?

```
var xCol = 'month'

var wraps = g.selectAll('.wrap').data(data);
  wraps.enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', 'wrap')
    .attr('transform', 'translate('+function(d){return xScale(d[xCol])}()+', '+ (-margin.top)+')')

>>>index.js:132 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'month' of undefined
```

And I want to make several groups `.wrap` and draw bars in each groups

But, I have no idea to forward data to child elements.

```
var bars = wraps.selectAll('.bar').data(function(d){return d});
  bars.enter().append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'bar')
    .attr('x', function(d){return xScale(d.d[xCol])})
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may just have the idea right but missing one small thing. The second argument to the attr function should be another function. Like below.

```
var svg = d3.select('svg');

var dataSet = [10, 20, 30, 40];

var circle = svg.selectAll('circle')
    .data(dataSet)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('r', function(d) {return d;})
    .attr('cx', function(d,i) {return i * 100 + 50;})
    .attr('cy', 50)
    .attr('fill', 'red')
```

So the function then returns the result. This fiddle shows it in action
http://jsfiddle.net/bdkxgph5/1/

So in your case replace you attr call with

```
.attr('transform', function(d) { return 'translate('+xScale(d[xCol])+', '+ (-margin.top)+')'})
```